# Can I install C in Win 7 64 bit machine?

Tags: c

Can I install C language in Win 7 64 bit OS? Do you know of any free softwares available online to install C for Win 7 64bit OS?

Comment: The C language is not a piece of software. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft providfe a free edition of visual studio

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify, what do you mean by C for x64?

You can write code for ANSI C95 using Visual Studio

Comment: Visual Studio does not support the current version of ANSI C.  The question has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: I want C language Compiler/Software for running C language code in my Win 7 machine

Answer (score 0):

C is not a program, but rather a standardized programming language.  You can install the [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) package, which is based on the popular free and open source GCC compiler.

Answer (score 0):

C is not a piece of software. It is a programming language which needs to be converted by software(s) in a form which is executable by the system. One of these softwares is a C compiler, which you need to have to compile the code.
You can always run 32bit compilers in 64bit OSes. Use DevC++ http://www.bloodshed.net/download.html ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to write some programs with c.
For beginners, I extremely recommend [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE. you must have mingw-w64 or any other compiler installed for it.